# System authentication in Android app

Tags: android, authentication

I want to authenticate my Android app using pin/password set for device security/lock screen. Is there any way to achieve this? May be, app will launch some system Activity, which will prompt for password. The system Activity should return success/failure.

Answer (score 2):

Began from Android 5.0, you can use [KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

This method will create an Intent, which can be used to start system authentication (pin / pattern / password).

For more information, refer [doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#Confirm-credential) and [Confirm Credential sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConfirmCredential).

Answer (score 0):

```
          App Start
(Is password already created?)  <--check in sharedPreferences(This is a good way to store info)
Yes                        No
Prompt for pass       Prompt for creation
Login if correct      Login
```

To do this you *can* use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), once you have stored a key you can retrieve it on app start up to decide what to do.

Comment: I don't want to store password in app. I want to use password set by user for device lockscreen.